# How can I use Google Latitude's Location History without a constant Internet connection?

Tags: google-location-history, google-latitude

I find the Location History part of Google Latitude really useful. Is there any way to make the app (or another) store my location when an Internet connection is not available, and send it to the Latitude servers as soon as a connection is available?

Answer (score 2):

[Latify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ecs.latify) in the Play Store does the trick.

Comment: Is the Latify project down? If yes, can you recommend a similar software?